# Azure Data Factory Trigger json file: Add all pipelines in pipelines property

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a value that can be entered that will apply the trigger to all pipelines in the branch? Currently I have to apply the trigger to each pipeline manually and in the future there will be more pipelines, if there is a value that applies to all then this would automate the process. I have not been able to find anything in Microsoft documents about it.

I have added the code of the current configuration with no pipelines added yet.

```
{

    "name": "DailyTrigger",

    "properties": {

        "description": "This trigger will execute once a day at 8am.",

        "annotations": [ ],

        "runtimeState": "Started",

        "pipelines": [ ],

        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",

        "typeProperties": {

            "recurrence": {

                "frequency": "Day",

                "interval": 1,

                "startTime": "2023-04-04T07:55:00",

                "timeZone": "GMT Standard Time",

                "schedule": {

                    "minutes": [

                        0

                    ],

                    "hours": [

                        8

                    ]

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Nothing I have tried so far has worked. I couldn't find a character or anything to use from looking.

Comment: Please enter code as text but not as image. So others can copy the code to give you a quick answer (and will not skip your question because of being annoyed by this PNG).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The following is a trigger that I have which has no pipelines attached.

[image]

You can achieve this requirement using Rest API. I have the run the following python code in Azure Databricks notebook.

```
#install msal using !pip install msal for getting bearer token
import msal
import requests
import json

tenant_id = '<tenant_id>'
client_id = '<client_id>'
client_secret = '<client_secret>'


app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=client_id, authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}", client_credential=client_secret)

# Get the token
scopes = ["https://management.azure.com/.default"]
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)
print(result)

# Set the endpoint URL for the trigger you want to update
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token'], 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

# Get the current trigger definition
trigger = requests.get(trigger_url, headers=headers).json()

trigger['properties']['pipelines'] = [{
                        "parameters": {},
                        "pipelineReference": {"referenceName": "pipeline1", "type": "PipelineReference"},
                    },{
                        "parameters": {},
                        "pipelineReference": {"referenceName": "pipeline2", "type": "PipelineReference"},
                    }]
# Send a PUT request to update the trigger
response = requests.put('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/triggers/{triggerName}?api-version=2018-06-01', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(updated_trigger)).json()
print(response)
```

[image]

- After executing the above code, I was able to attach the trigger to required pipelines.

[image]

- If you want to further automate this process, use another Rest API `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines?api-version=2018-06-01` which returns the details of all pipelines (GET method).
- If you want to start the trigger, you can use the API `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/triggers/{triggerName}/start?api-version=2018-06-01` (POST method)

**NOTE:** Create a service principle first and add role assignment to this app in your azure data factory. I have assigned it Contributor role.